# PHP/SQL - Add values together if ID is the same in foreach()

Tags: php, sql, foreach

I am trying to show statistics for goals scored by players, however sometimes the same player is added to the database with the same playerID, when a player is added twice how can I add the values together to show it as a total, rather than echo the player twice.

db structure example:

```
playerID | Goals | Season | leagueID
   1         5       1        1
   2         1       1        1
   1         2       1        2
   5         3       1        1
   1         3       2        2
   2         2       2        1
```

php:

```
$query = $db->query('SELECT * FROM playerstats ORDER BY goals DESC LIMIT 30');
$num = $query->num_rows;
if($num > 0) {

foreach($query as $row) {
$playerID = $row['playerID'];
$goals = $row['goals'];

echo '
<tr>
<td>'.$playerID.'</td>
<td>'.$goals.'</td>
</tr>

';

}

}
```

This would show playerID 1, 3 seperate times.
How can I make it show playerID 1 just once with all the goals added together (10)

I have tried changing the query to: SELECT DISTINCT * FROM playerstats ORDER BY goals DESC LIMIT 30 but this made no difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Group BY will help you:

```
<?php
$query = $db->query('SELECT SUM(p.goals) as total_goals, 
p.playerID, p.leagueID, p.Season 
FROM playerstats as p 
GROUP BY p.playerID, p.leagueID, p.Season
ORDER BY total_goals DESC LIMIT 30');

$num = $query->num_rows;
if($num > 0) {
foreach($query as $row) {        
   echo '
    <tr>
    <td>'.$row['playerID'].'</td>
    <td>'.$row['total_goals'].'</td>
    </tr>

    ';

  }
```

}

Please note, that my query will group also by season and leagues, if you want total goals throughs seasons and leagues, your `group by` will be:
`GROUP BY p.playerID`

Answer (score 5):

If you want only the `playerID` and the sum of the `goals` not mattering the `Season` or the `leagueID`, change your query to:

`SELECT DISTINCT playerID AS player, 
       (SELECT SUM(goals) FROM playerstats WHERE playerID = player) AS totalGoals 
 FROM playerstats`

Answer (score 1):

Well you would group results in array then loop over it. Or sort at SQL level.
Something like this might work:

```
    $playerStats = array();

    foreach($query as $row)
    {    
        if(array_key_exists($row['playerID'], $playerStats))
            $playerStats[$row['playerID']] += $row['goals'];
        else
            $playerStats[$row['playerID']] = $row['goals'];
    }

    // Then loop over playerStats

    foreach($playerStats as $playerID => $playerGoals)
    }
        echo $playerID;
        echo $playerGoals;
    {
```